# Access Violation Error while trying to make a memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, malloc

```
struct DynamicArray {
       int allocated;
       int used;
       int *array;  
}; typedef struct DynamicArray DynamicArray;

DynamicArray * ArrayCreate(int initialSize) {
       DynamicArray *array;
       (*array).array = (int*)malloc(initialSize*sizeof(int)); //Debugger points this line.
       if((*array).array == NULL) {
            return NULL;    
       }
       (*array).allocated = initialSize;
       (*array).used=0;
       return array;
}
```

I am trying to make my own library for dynamic arrays. Just to learn and improve myself. Please review my code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are de-referencing an uninitialized pointer here:

```
DynamicArray *array;  // uninitialized
(*array).array = .... // ooops
```

You need to make `array` point to some memory you can write to. For example

```
DynamicArray *array = malloc(sizeof(DynamicArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

First use this :

```
DynamicArray *array;
array = (DynamicArray *)malloc(sizeof(struct DynamicArray));
array->array = ...
```

If you don't initialize a point you can't dereference it because its point to NULL.